# How to test a specific spec.ts file in Angular 4?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I am a novice in Angular. I am using Angular 4 in my current project.I was learning Unit testing with angular, just wanted to know if I can test a specific spec.ts file alone.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: when i give ng test in angular CLI it is testing the whole project.

Comment: It doesn't have much to do with Angular. Rename your `describe` to `fdescribe` or your `it` to `fit`, and only that method will be executed.

Comment: What ide are you using? In Webstorms, you can right click a spec file and click "run '<spec file name>"

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First go to the component into the spec.ts file of the component.
then put f in front of `it` and `describe` so you end up with `fdescribe` and `fit`.

Then go to console or terminal then execute `ng test`.

The above command will execute only `fdescribe` and `fit` test cases only, other ones will be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

Prefix the `describe` with `f` such as `fdescribe`

Comment: I changed the describe and it to fdescribe and fit respectively in app.component.spec.ts

Answer (score -1):

Use `fdescribe` instead of `describe` and it will run only the tests inside of this `fdescribe` block. Also IntelliJ / Webstorm allow you to test single file from the context menu